# Django migrations duplicate/already exists problem

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration

I have a fairly large code base in django, with several applications, and at some point I had a problem: every time I change or add models and try to do a migration, an error appears: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "appname_modelname" already exists. The problem has been going on for some time - the migration file is always created under the same number - 0114 (I could not find this file, by the way), and all new fixes are recorded in it along with the previous ones, which is why the problem grows, like snowball.

I did not want to delve into the solution and just manually removed all the innovations from the database - everything that caused the "already exists" conflict to appear. So, in order for the migration to succeed, I had to manually delete all models or table fields that I created after this problem appeared. But now I'm starting to work in prod with this code and fill it with data, and it is no longer possible to delete all the data from the corresponding tables. I have no idea why this problem appeared and how to solve it and would really appreciate your advice.

I tried to make a fake, but then, obviously, the fixes I need simply do not get into the database.
I have a hypothesis as to what caused this: I have three docker containers, one api, and two for celery. In the api container, I wrote the command in the bash file at startup

`python3 /usr/srv/h_api/src/manage.py makemigrations && python3 /usr/srv/h_api/src/manage.py migrate`

instead of

`python3 /usr/srv/h_api/src/manage.py makemigrations`

so I don't have to do it manually every time. I don't understand why, but judging by the coincidence of time, it seems that the problem started because of this. It's been weeks since I changed that line back, but the problem remains.

How do I commit previous changes to the database and have django create the next migration file numbered 0115?

Comment: Have you tried faking the 0114 and then making migrations to create the 0115?

Comment: @mendespedro Just tried it. I made a test field for one model. Did ...migrate --fake, then again makemigrations. Received a response "no change detected". But after all of this when I try to open this model in the admin panel, a programming error occurs, because this field is not in the database.

Comment: @mendespedro After that, I deleted this field, rebuilt the container, and at the start, the makemigrations made the 0114 file again with everything the same that I fake migrated last time

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit risky but it has worked for me in the past. I suggest creating a copy of your project in another folder and trying this safely away from the original project. Also if you are using a postgresql database then just switch to a dummy database although it shouldn't make a difference but just to be on the safer side.

Inside of your migrations folder, inside the app folder, try deleting the all the files inside of *pycache* EXCEPT **init**.cpython-39.pyc and 0001_initial.cpython-39.pyc and inside of the migrations folder delete all files EXCEPT **init**.py and 0001_initial.py.

IMPORTANT: Delete from the pycache INSIDE of migrations NOT the one outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

> 

The approach below has often helped me out, if its a production database its good to backup and also your migrations folder before getting started.

- Start by deleting your current applications migrations folder
- temporarily add a field to your models.
- Makemigrations then migrate
- Delete the temporarily added field from your model
- Makemigrations and migrate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).